# Spoofing JavaScript compatibility

Tags: javascript, android, http, browser

I am trying to write an app that simply acts as an interface to a website that already exists. There's no API, so it's going to be a lot of POSTing, GETing, and XML parsing.

Problem 1: "You need to enable JavaScript in your browser."

How can I spoof their server into thinking that I am a fully capable browser? Or, really, that I am JavaScript-enabled?

Comment: Spoof the server into thinking you are a JavaScript-enabled browser? Server and Browser+JavaScript are two different things. I believe the server never knows, actually, never cares to, because it doesn't need to. The server will get a request and send a response based on what you asked it to. It doesn't care if you can execute JavaScript or not, it will just spit it out all to your browser, which will do the cooking with JS.

Comment: The only good way a server can tell, IIRC, is by trying to provide a cookie and then testing for it. The expectation, though, is for them to serve non-script content in `<noscript>` tags. Do you have a specific site that's causing a problem?

Comment: Actually, I'm just an idiot. I'm going to delete this question, but just in case you were curious, I thought that they were testing my JS compatibility on the backend. But, now that I've actually looked at the source, it's simply a warning in a <noscript> block.

Comment: you could add the comment as an answer, and tell the story there for future googlers who think they are looking for the same thing?

Comment: I suppose I could keep this up for posterity's sake. Thanks for the feedback all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unlikely that JavaScript compatibility is being tested server-side. In my case, it was not -- the source of the page I was looking at simply had a warning in a `<noscript>` block. In the latter case, it's easy to simply ignore the warning and proceed as usual.